# Getting sizeof(PGconn) with libpq

Tags: c, postgresql, gcc, libpq

I'm attempting to wrap libpq for a program, and part of the FFI tool I'm using attempts to get `sizeof()` any struct in use.  In this case the issue is that trying to get `sizeof(PGconn)` results in a bunch of errors from GCC because it is an incomplete type.  Is there a way to get the same data, or do I need to train to this FFI tool to ignore types that are intended to be opaque?  For reference here is the generated C code, and the compiler errors:

```
/* Define on Darwin to activate all library features */
#define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
/* This must be set to 64 on some systems to enable large file support. */
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
/* Define on Linux to activate all library features */
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
/* This must be defined on some systems to enable large file support. */
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE 1
/* Define on NetBSD to activate all library features */
#define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
/* Define to activate features from IEEE Stds 1003.1-2001 */
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
/* Define on FreeBSD to activate all library features */
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
#define __XSI_VISIBLE 700
/* Windows: winsock/winsock2 mess */
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <libpq-fe.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>   /* for offsetof() */

void dump(char* key, int value) {
    printf("%s: %d\n", key, value);
}


void dump_section_PGconn(void) {
    typedef PGconn platcheck_t;
    typedef struct {
        char c;
        platcheck_t s;
    } platcheck2_t;

    platcheck_t s;
    dump("align", offsetof(platcheck2_t, s));
    dump("size",  sizeof(platcheck_t));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("-+- PGconn\n");
    dump_section_PGconn();
    printf("---\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And the errors:

```
[platform:execute] gcc -c -O3 -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-unused -I/usr/include/postgresql/ /tmp/usession-default-52/platcheck_10.c -o /tmp/usession-default-52/platcheck_10.o
[platform:Error] /tmp/usession-default-52/platcheck_10.c: In function ‘dump_section_PGconn’:
[platform:Error] /tmp/usession-default-52/platcheck_10.c:34: error: field ‘s’ has incomplete type
[platform:Error] /tmp/usession-default-52/platcheck_10.c:37: error: storage size of ‘s’ isn’t known
[platform:Error] /tmp/usession-default-52/platcheck_10.c:39: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘platcheck_t’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PGConn` is opaque by design.   If you need to look into it, include `libpq-int.h` (for "internal").  But consider reconsidering your requirements instead.

Answer (score 2):

When I search for `PGConn` on Google, everything I see has you dealing with `PGConn*` instead of `PGConn`.  My guess is that you're meant to deal with these as an opaque type through a pointer.

But I did find [this](http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/libpq-and-pgconn-struct-607931.html) that references [the source](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/libpq-int_8h-source.html).  Perhaps that is helpful to you.